# Find all duplicate records in SQL table with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I want to create a datagrid which contains all the records with then same name.

I have this table:

```
Shop
ID name          adress            city
-----------------------------------------
1  name1         adress 1          city1
2  name 2        adress2           city2
3  name 2        
4  name 2                          city2
5  name 3        
6  name 4        adress4           city4
7  name 4        adress4           city4
```

and my datagrid must contain:

```
2  name 2        adress2           city2
3  name 2        
4  name 2                          city2
6  name 4        adress4           city4
7  name 4        adress4           city4
```

but I have no idea how to create this query

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you use Entity Framework I assume you use LINQ as well.

In which case, try it this way:

```
var duplicates = Shop.GroupBy(i => i.Name)
                     .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
                     .Select(val => val.Key);

foreach(var item in duplicates)
{
    //process
}
```

In a simple example the output would look like this:
[image: Linqpad example]

**//EDIT:**

if you want to group by multiple columns you can use this syntax:

```
var query = (from sh in Shop
     group sh by new {sh.Name, sh.Address, sh.City} into grp
     select new
     {
        name = grp.Key.Name,
        address = grp.Key.Address,
        city = grp.Key.City
     }).ToList()
       .GroupBy(q => q.name)
       .Where (q => q.Count() >1)
       .Dump();
```

This will result in the following:

[image: second result]

**//EDIT2:**
sometimes I am borderline stupid.
Following the KISS-principle:

```
var query = Shop.GroupBy (s => s.Name).Where (s => s.Count () > 1).Dump();
```

Comment: If I do like that, I have just one line by duplicates records. But I Want to watch all my duplicates records to select the records that I want delete

Comment: the first query groups only by name and gives you ALL duplicates, as shown in my "picture-example". If you can provide us some code, maybe we could find an error.

Comment: There is no error. it's just not what I want. If you read my exemple, you can see that I want the details of the duplicates lines in my result. In your exemple I would:{3,3,4,4,6,6,7,7...}

Comment: Sorry, I have plainly misunderstood you. I have extended my answer to reflect your (hopefully correct) needs.

Comment: Dump() extension method exists only in LinqPad

Comment: Don't mention it. Took me long enough to wrap my head around it ... for whatever reason. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
select name, adress, city
from tab
where name in ( select name
                from tab
                group by name
                having count(name) >1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var groupedByName = from shop in Shops
                    group shop by new shop.Name into grp
                    where grp.Count() > 1
                    select grp
```

should do the work. The result is an Igrouping with a set of values (Shops) grouped by Name, where the Key of the group is the Name property of Shop.

Sorry but it was too long to be placed in a comment.

Comment: This does not account for duplicates, you need to add a `where clause`