# Find all duplicate records in SQL table with Entity Framework by Multiple colums

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I try to refactor this query to an EF query:

```
SELECT 
    PS_Adressen.AdName, PS_Adressen.AdVorname, 
    PS_Adressen.AdStrasse, PS_Adressen.AdStrasseNr, PS_Adressen.AdPLZ6  
FROM
    PS_Besuch 
JOIN 
    PS_Adressen ON PS_Besuch.BeAdNr = PS_Adressen.Adnr 
WHERE
    BeAbMonat = @Month 
    AND BeHostessNr = @Nr 
    AND (PS_Besuch.BeKoffer = 1 OR PS_Besuch.BeKoffer = 2 
         OR PS_Besuch.BeKoffer = 3) 
GROUP BY
    PS_Adressen.AdName, PS_Adressen.AdVorname, 
    PS_Adressen.AdStrasse, PS_Adressen.AdStrasseNr, PS_Adressen.AdPLZ6 
HAVING
    COUNT(BeNr) > 1
```

I found this post: [Find all duplicate records in SQL table with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955987/find-all-duplicate-records-in-sql-table-with-entity-framework)

But this only enables me to check if a single value like the name is duplicate, but not different columns.

I started with:

```
var query = from visit in db.Visits
            join address in db.Addresses on visit.AddressId equals address.Id
            group address by new {
                        address.Name,
                        address.Prename,
                        address.Street,
                        address.StreetNr,
                        address.Zip,
                        address.ZipLong,
                        visit.VisitNr
                    } into temp
            select  new {
                    Name = temp.Key.Name,
                    Prename = temp.Key.Prename,
                    Street = temp.Key.Street,
                    StreetNr = temp.Key.StreetNr,
                    Zip = temp.Key.Zip,
                    ZipLong = temp.Key.ZipLong,
                    VisitNr = temp.Key.VisitNr
                };

var list = query.Where(x => x.VisitNr.Count() > 1).ToList();
```

But here the where clause is not correct. Something with the Count seems wrong..

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks
NPadrutt

Comment: Could you point out what specifically you're having issues with? If you just generally don't know where to start with translating SQL to LINQ to Entities you'll need to go through some tutorials on EF.

Comment: I can select and group, but then I couldn't find a way to translate this having to Linq.. I added some code of my latest code. Since I already tried a lot of things the grouping is already outside of the query.

Comment: Thanks for adding your code, that helps. Could you show what you're actually using for the third parameter, since that's where you say the problem is occurring?

Comment: I changed my code again. That is what I have tried in the first place. The problem is that the count() seems not to work..

Comment: what do you mean seems not to work, is it an error?

Comment: He cannot find the symbol. But the solution if sohaty seems to work for me. I'll do my tests afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var query = from visit in db.Visits

                    join address in db.Addresses on visit.AddressId equals address.Id

                    group address by new {
                        address.Name,
                        address.Prename,
                        address.Street,
                        address.StreetNr,
                        address.Zip,
                        address.ZipLong
                    } into temp
                select  new {
                    Name = temp.Key.Name,
                    Prename = temp.Key.Prename,
                    Street = temp.Key.Street,
                    StreetNr = temp.Key.StreetNr,
                    Zip = temp.Key.Zip,
                    ZipLong = temp.Key.ZipLong,
                    RecCount = temp.Count()
                };

            var list = query.Where(x => x.RecCount > 1).ToList();
```

Comment: Are the source tables for original script and linqquery the same? I am confused by the different names of tables and fields, as well as a different number of fields in a table [addresses]

Comment: yeah they are the same. but since the db has a rather bad naming i set new name for them.

Comment: ok. Exclude the [VisitNr] column from the linq-query. This field doesn't present int the sql-script, then it should not be used in the query. I've edited Answer above.